# BsonElement attribute and custom deserialization logic with MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Consider the following example:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        private string _text;

        [BsonElement("text"), BsonRequired]
        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set
            {
                _text = value;
                Bar(_text);
            }
        }

        private void Bar(string text)
        {
            //Only relevant when Text is set by the user of the class,
            //not during deserialization
        }
    }
```

The setter of the `Text` property and, subsequently, the method `Bar` are called both when the user of the class assigns a new value to the property and during object deserialization by the MongoDB C# driver. What I need is to ensure that `Bar` is called only when the `Text` property is set by the user and not during deserialization.

I see two solutions which don't really suit me:

The first is to move the `BsonElement` attribute to the backing field. However, as far as I know, the `BsonElement` attribute is used in query building by the MongoDB C# driver, so I will lose the ability to use the `Text` property in queries.

The second solution is to make the `Text` setter private and add a method through which the user of the class will set the `Text` property, and in which the `Bar` method would be called. However, the `Text` setter is used very often in the existing solution, and I'm a bit reluctant to change 70+ calls across all files. Plus, the code will become less readable.

Is there any cleaner way to separate deserialization and user-prompted property change while retaining the `BsonElement` attribute on the property?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but I'd still like to help for other people stumbling on this issue as I have done.

It basically boils down to something very simple: serialization and deserialization are not limited to public fields and properties!

The next example will cover the original question without having to invent dubious secondary properties:

```
public class Foo
{
    [BsonElement("Text"), BsonRequired]
    private string _text;

    [BsonIgnore]
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            Bar(_text);
        }
    }

    private void Bar(string text)
    {
        //Only relevant when Text is set by the user of the class,
        //not during deserialization
    }
}
```

Simply put your `BsonElement` class on the backing field and tell it to `BsonIgnore` the property.
You can do whatever you like in the getter and setter without having to worry about deserialization which now occurs on private field level.

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a seperate property for the users and for the DB for the same private variable, something like this,

```
public class Foo
{
    private string _text;

    [BsonElement("text"), BsonRequired]
    public string TextDB
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
        }
    }

    [BsonIgnore]
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            Bar(_text);
        }
    }

    private void Bar(string text)
    {
        //Only relevant when Text is set by the user of the class,
        //not during deserialization
    }
}
```

Comment: But then I will lose the ability to query by the Text property, right? It's not a bad solution, you could still query by TextDB, but this won't be obvious to the user of the class unless he reads the comments or the implementation.

Comment: Im not sure im following your question. Data access layer would reference TextDB property and your client calls will use Text property. Since they are pointing to the same data you should not have any issue with consistency. Better yet, mark the TextDB as internal so other layers may not be able to access them.

Comment: Please note: there is a special case with the Bson serialization which converts Id => _id, as MongoDB requires _id field, so trying to use [BsonElement("_id")] doesn't work if there is still public string Id in your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little trick an implement a kind of property listener.

The usage would be:

```
// Working with some foo here...
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Text = "Won't fire anything";

using (var propertyListener = new FooPropertiesListener(foo))
{
    foo.Text = "Something will fire you listener";
}

// Some more work with foo here...
foo.Text = "Won't fire anything";
```

And the implementation behind it, something like:

**FooPropertiesListener**

```
public class FooPropertiesListener : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Foo Foo;

    public FooPropertiesListener(Foo foo)
    {
        this.Foo = foo;
        this.Foo.PropertiesListener = this;
    }

    public void Bar(string text)
    {
        //Only relevant when Text is set by the user of the class,
        //not during deserialization
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Foo.PropertiesListener = null;
    }
}
```

**Foo**

```
public class Foo
{
    internal FooPropertiesListener PropertiesListener;

    private string _text;

    [BsonElement("text"), BsonRequired]
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            if (PropertiesListener != null)
            {
                PropertiesListener.Bar(_text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't really what I was looking for - invoking `Bar` on `Text` property change is the default behavior, and the user of the class shouldn't be required to take additional steps to ensure this behavior.