# How to save a private field with LiteDB

Tags: c#, litedb

**Is there an attribute for private properties to be stored with the LiteDB engine?**

I want to store this property in the LiteDB database

```
private string SomeGoodPropertyName { get; set; }
```

Is there an exact opposite of the `[BsonIgnore]` attribute, (like "`[BsonInclude]`") which includes private fields in the storage process?

I tried to simply set the `[BsonField]` attribute, but that did not help, and I looked at Mappers, but as far as I saw all of them rely on the field being public.

Here is an example of why I would want to do that:
I have the following class:

```
public class Authenticator {
    private string AuthenticationString { get; set; }
    private CashRegisterType ActiveCashRegisterType { get; set; }
    public void SetAuthenticationString(string authString, CashRegisterType type)
    {
       //Perform some validation
       ...

       AuthenticationString = authString;
       ActiveCashRegisterType = type;
    }

    public string GetAuthenticatorString(CashRegisterType type){
       //Validate request -> returns null if validation failed
       ...

       return AuthenticationString;
    }
}
```

This object should now be stored in the database (as a child object of another document). I do not want the two properties to be public, because I have to perform the validation before setting and getting it, but I want to store the data on the disk.

Comment: Why do you want to bsoninclude, its a matter of not giving [bsoninclude] so that it will be included

Comment: In my case private properties are not included. Only public ones. Can I configure something differently?

Comment: the idea of private is encapsulation, why you want private property to be exposed/included?

Comment: I'll give an example in the question

Comment: I hope this example shows why I would want to do that. Is something else wrong in my "architecture" here?

Comment: BsonRequired try this and let me know

Comment: see this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406063/bsonelement-attribute-and-custom-deserialization-logic-with-mongodb-c-sharp-driv

Comment: The LiteDB library does not define the "BsonRequired" tag. It suggest installing the MongoDB nuget package... I guess the "BsonRequired" Attribute would solve the issue for MongoDB, but it does not help in my case. The code does not compile.

Comment: Looks like you need to achieve it without using BsonInclude , some other ways might be there ..i am not sure

Comment: Mhh thanks for the attempt to help. I did not find anything on the GitHub Wiki about this...